# Haskell Best Practise: Early termination in Haskeline

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskeline

I am using the [Haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) package and I want to get three strings in a row from the command line before I do anything and I have come up with what seems to be a neat solution to me. But I am sure that there might be a better way to do it. I am looking for best practices while using the Haskeline package. Please evaluate the merits of the following example code:

```
import System.Console.Haskeline
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Maybe
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = runInputT defaultSettings (runMaybeT getStrings) >>= print

getStrings :: MaybeT (InputT IO) (String, String, String)
getStrings = do
   mone <- lift $ getInputLine "food> "
   notNothing mone
   mtwo <- lift $ getInputLine "drink> "
   notNothing mtwo
   mthree <- lift $ getInputLine "dessert> "
   notNothing mthree
   return (fromJust mone, fromJust mtwo, fromJust mthree)
      where
         notNothing a = guard (a /= Nothing)
```

As you can see it accomplishes the task of early termination but it looks a bit yucky still. I'm thinking of trying to convert the notNothing's and the getInputLine's into a single line like:

```
mone <- notNothing =<< lift $ getInputLine "food> " -- does not type check
```

Which I think does not look that bad. I think that is pretty clear and concise (though it does not type check so I will have to write a version that does).

However, this is the best I have come up with and my question finally is: How would you go about improving this code to be neater and more readily readable? Am I even on the right track?

**Edit**: If your guard is something other than 'a /= Nothing' then a nice helper function that I just discovered is:

```
myGuard s = guard (someConditionFunc s) >> s
```

Because then you can write (as [luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33796/luqui) suggested):

```
mone <- myGuard =<< (lift $ getInputLine prompt)
```

Which is pretty cool. But if you are matching against only Nothing then TomMD's answer is better.

Comment: I think your combined line doesn't work because of the precedence of `$`; try `mone <- notNothing =<< lift (getInputLine "food> ")`

Comment: If you're interested in best practices in general, you should use hlint on your code.

Comment: @amccausl I do but it would not have suggested this I don't think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just leverage the fact that `fail _ = Nothing` for the Maybe monad?

```
mthree <- lift $ getInputLine "dessert> "
notNothing mthree
```

becomes

```
Just mthree <- lift $ getInputLine "dessert> "
```

Comment: Very Nice!! It seems blindingly obvious in retrospect! Any more excellent suggestions? (Though I doubt it can get much smaller than it is now)

Answer (score 4):

How about a helper function?

```
inputLine :: String -> MaybeT (InputT IO) String
inputLine prompt = do
    m <- lift $ getInputLine prompt
    case m of
        Just x -> return x
        Nothing -> mzero
```

This can be shortened considerably using various tricks, but I wanted to be clear.  Now you can just forget that `getInputLine` can fail, `MaybeT` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Your right! The best helper function (imo) is 'myGuard a = guard (condition_with_a) >> return a' because then you can say 'm <- myGuard =<< (lift $ getInputLine prompt)'